# how to paginate the retrieved data from mysql database by using php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i have a search page in my site, where user can search all the data from the database.i have a table in database named property from which all searched data fetched.
now i want to add pagination to my result page and want only show 8 records on first page.
my website is in wordpress and code of retrieve data according to search is as follows:

```
<?php  

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
        {
          $search = $_POST['cs'];
 $field_array = array('ID', 'ManagementCompanyID', 'MarketingName', 'PropertyURL', 'Address', 'City', 'State', 'PostalCode', 'StructureType', 'UnitCount', 'YearBuilt', 'LeaseLength', 'Parking', 'ShortDescription');

           foreach($field_array as $value)
           {
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `wp_property` WHERE `$value` LIKE '%$search%' ";
             $result = mysql_query($query);
             while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                             {
                                    echo "<pre>";
                                      print_r($row);
                                     echo "<pre>";
                             }
}

}

?>
```

the elements of $field_array are columns of wp_property table.
any help will be appreciate..
thanks in advance

Comment: Sending queries in a loop is a bad idea. Use `OR` to combine multiple criteria in a single query.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: It's not, just use transactions, and not `mysql_*` functions

Comment: That might be true for queries that modify data. But SELECTing in a loop won't be improved by using transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php  

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { // DO NOT USE $_REQUEST unless You are sure You need this... Use $_GET or $_POST accordingly...
    $search = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cs']); // ALWAYS sanitize user input
    $field_array = array('ID', 'ManagementCompanyID', 'MarketingName', 'PropertyURL', 'Address', 'City', 'State', 'PostalCode', 'StructureType', 'UnitCount', 'YearBuilt', 'LeaseLength', 'Parking', 'ShortDescription');

    // Pagination
    $limit = 15; // change that constant if You want or let it be a value from form...
    $offset = isset($_POST['page']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['page']) : 0;
    $offset = $offset * $limit;

    $where = ' WHERE (';
    $cnt = count($field_array);
    $i = 0;
    foreach($field_array as $value) {
        $where .= " {$value} LIKE '%{$search}%'";
        if($i < $cnt) $where .= ' OR ';
        $i++;
    }
    $where .= ')';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `wp_property` {$where} LIMIT {$offset}, {$limit}";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($row);
        echo "<pre>";
    }
}
```

Now by changing `$_POST['page']` value to `1`, `2`, `3` ... You paginate through the data... Make Your HTML part of the pagination however You want (links, buttons, etc...).

I would recomend not using `mysql_*` functions, at least use `mysqli` or `PDO`.